# PhoneGap App Build-time Settings

Tags: cordova

I would like to know where is a good place to store build-time generated variables, like the server address, that I can mutate during a msbuild-like process. These variables have to be able to be read from my PhoneGap app later. I am looking for something close to the XML app.config file that can be mutated using XML transformation tools.